# Code Review for Adding two numbers without using the + operator

Tags: java

Here's my code. Please review it for correctness, readability and efficiency. If you think it can be improved also let me know. This code works fine for positive numbers but doesn't for negative. How can I change it ? Any comments for improvement will be appreciated.

```
int sum(int a, int b)
    {
       int sum = 0;
       int carry = 0;
       int mask = 1;
       sum = doAdd(a,b,mask,carry, 0);
       return sum;
    }

    int doAdd(int a,int b, int mask, int carry, int sum)
    {
       int aBit = a&mask;
       int bBit = b&mask;

       if(mask<a||mask<b||carry!=0)
       {
          sum = sum | (carry^aBit^bBit);
          carry = (carry==0) ? (aBit&bBit) : (carry&a|carry&b);
          mask = mask << 1;
          if(carry!=0)
          carry = mask;
          return (doAdd(a,b,mask,carry, sum));
       }

       return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm looks good, but the best algorithm (as far as I know) is following:

1. Add 2 binary numbers without considering carry (an xor operation)
2. Construct the difference with the actual solution, i.e., construct a number in the carry positions (a and operation then a left shift)
3. Add the result of step 1 with step 2 (by recursion), until step2 is 0.

The code will look like this:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) return a;
    return add(a ^ b, (a & b) << 1);
}
```

Comment: why does you step#2 work ?

Comment: We can mathametically prove that the algorithm will converge (step 2 will eventually become zero).

Comment: The proof goes like this: if we can prove that (a & b) << 1) will have less or equal number of 1 bits as b, then the algorithm will converge. Since "b is bitwise and" with a, it will always have less or equal number of 1 bits than b. So, the algorithm will converge (WORST CASE SCENARIO: a has same 1 bit positions as b for all the recursive calls, even then because of the left shift (a&b)<<1 will eventtually have less number of 1 bit than b). I did not want to tap into theoritical computer science, but hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Nice.

Start by following Java [Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-139411.html#16712); 8.2 asks for spaces around binary operators.

Add a unit test with nested loops that compares your results with `+` results.

There's no need for temp variables (though they *do* have nice self documenting names!) in `sum()`; it would be enough to just have it invoke the helper function like this: `return doAdd(a, b, 0x1, 0, 0)`. Consider renaming `doAdd` to `sum1` to more clearly show how they're related. Consider renaming the final argument to `acc` or `accumulator`.

Adding a comment (or an `assert`) that points out that `mask` only has a single bit on would be an aid to the reader. Another way to do that would be to change the API so `currentBitPosition` is what's passed in, and then immediately assign `mask = 1 << currentBitPosition`.

There seems to be a typo - looks like you wanted `carry & aBit...`. Oh, wait, now I see, carry can be as large as mask. Wow, that's surprising. Rename it to carryMask. Better yet, change the type to boolean to minimize reader surprise. Maybe refactor to:

```
...
sum |= carry ^ aBit ^ bBit;
carry = carry ? (aBit | bBit) : (aBit & bBit);
mask <<= 1;   (or: mask *= 2)
...
```

As far as signed arithmetic goes, you're going to have to declare your word length, and turn the comparison between `mask` and `a` into a test of whether `mask` is about to overflow. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Formal tip : as you past *zero* and do nothing with *sum* you can remove it :

```
int sum(int a, int b)
    {
       int carry = 0;
       int mask = 1;
       return doAdd(a,b,mask,carry, 0);
    }
```